# Why did "None" came as the second output for my one line code in python?

Tags: python-3.x

print(print("Hello World!"))

and the output is :

Hello World!
None

Comment: you have two print commands here, the second one prints the output of the first print command, which is `None`, i.e. the print command only prints to the stdout and returns `None`

Comment: Please research your question before asking -  google  + `python print prints None site:stackoverflow.com` returns a plethora of fitting results.

Answer (score 0):

The [`print` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) has no return value, i.e. it returns `None`.

(What did you expect to get with the second `print`?)